# python try and except url correction Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the HTML from web pages. However, not all URL's are correctly written. Most invalid URL's in the list include http, but now the URL's are using https. Some are missing "www.", and with others "www." needs to be added.

```
def repl_www_http(url):
    x = url.replace("www.", "")
    y = x.replace("http", "https")
    return y

def repl_www(url):
    y = url.replace("www.", "")
    return y

def repl_http(url):
    y = url.replace("http", "https")
    return y

def repl_no_www(url):
    y = url.replace("//", "//www.")
    return y

def get_html(urllist):
        for i in urllist:
            html = ""
            try:
                html = requests.get(i)
                html = html.text
                return html
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                try:
                    html = requests.get(repl_http(i))
                    html = html.text
                    print("replaced // with //www.")
                except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                    try:
                        html = requests.get(repl_http(i))
                        html = html.text
                        print("replaced http with https")
                        return html
                    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                        try:
                            html = requests.get(repl_www(i))
                            html = html.text
                            print("replaced www. with .")
                            return html
                        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                            try:
                                html = requests.get(repl_www_http(i))
                                html = html.text
                                print("replaced www with . and http with https")
                                return html
                            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                                return "no HTML found on this URL"
        print("gethtml finished", html)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\replacer.py", line 76, in <module>    html = get_html(i)
  File "C:\replacer.py", line 37, in get_html    html = requests.get(repl_http(i))
  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py3.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py3.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py3.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 498, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py3.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 441, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py3.7.egg\requests\models.py",line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py3.7.egg\requests\models.py",
line 383, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
```

How can I solve this issue to correct the wrong URL's?

Comment: What is `repl_http`?

Comment: def repl_www_http(url):
    x = url.replace("www.", "")
    y = x.replace("http", "https")
    return y

def repl_www(url):
    y = url.replace("www.", "")
    return y

def repl_http(url):
    y = url.replace("http", "https")
    return y

def repl_no_www(url):
    y = url.replace("//", "//www.")
    return y

Comment: Can you please put this into your question?

Comment: I did! This is my first question on Stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Did you try printing the `url` you're analyzing? It could be that your `repl_http` function is not working as you expect and is returing only an `h` as url.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that url passed to requests.get() send MissingSchema errors, and you should catch this error as you catch ConnectionError.

I think you should use a generator to clean your code, because you shouldn't embed try/catch statements like this.

```
def get_versions_url(my_url):
    yield my_url
    yield repl_www(my_url)
    yield repl_http(my_url)
    yield repl_http_www(my_url)

def get_html(urllist):
    #use i only for indexes
    for my_url in urllist:
        for url_fixed in get_versions_url(my_url):
            try:
                # I dind't figure out why you return here and do not end first loop
                return requests.get(url_fixed).text
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                pass
            except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
                pass
```

Then you can debug your generator.
Try to do :

```
for url in fix_url(<your url>):
    print(url)
```

I think some of yours repl_ function does not work as you expect.